# What is the difference between UseStaticFiles, UseSpaStaticFiles, and UseSpa in ASP.NET Core 2.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-2.1

ASP.NET Core 2.1.1 offers several seemingly related extension methods for appBuilder:

- `UseStaticFiles` from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles`
- `UseSpaStaticFiles` from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions`
- `UseSpa` from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions`

**Please help me make sense of their purpose and relation to each other?**

Also, is there any difference from the server execution standpoint if I run these methods in a different order

e.g.

```
app.UseStaticFiles() -> app.UseSpaStaticFiles() -> app.UseSpa()
```

vs

```
app.UseSpa() -> app.UseSpaStaticFiles() -> app.UseStaticFiles()
```

Comment: The "Spa" version of these methods are for Single Page Applications.

Comment: @Darkonekt could you elaborate? I know what the SPAs are. I don't understand what are the specifics of these different methods.

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko did my answer solve your problem ? If it does please mark my answer as accepted answer.

Comment: @NgôHùngPhúc I'm still unsure... Added a clarifying pair of questions

Answer (score 56, accepted):

> Static files, such as HTML, CSS, images, and JavaScript, are assets an
>   ASP.NET Core app serves directly to clients. Some configuration is
>   required to enable serving of these files.

- UseStaticFiles - Serve files inside of web root (wwwroot folder)
- UseSpaStaticFiles - Serve static file like image, css, js in asset
  folder of angular app
- UseSpa - let asp.net core know which directory you want to run your
  angular app, what dist folder when running in production mode and
  which command to run angular app in dev mode

Example

```cs
services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
{
 configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
});

app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
    // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

    spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
    }
});
```

Comment: SPA application is just static files that are served to a client. Therefore, `UseStaticFiles` should be sufficient for serving a SPA if I wanted to, right? Is the only "benefit" of `UseSpaStaticFiles` is the ability to specify a non-wwwroot directory for SPA?

Comment: I think you can but if you using UseStaticFile to sever Spa file how can you run in dev mode ? It's okay to run in prod mode because you can specific the folder path. But in the example code using services.AddSpaStaticFile they using command to run your code in prod mode. Otherwise you have to manual include script tag in your view manually when you use UseStaticFile

Comment: In my scenario, I'd only use `UseStaticFile` for prod mode. For dev mode I am running a trivial bash command like `yarn start` (with `create-react-app`) or a `serve` with the built `dist` directory... What I'm hearing is that all of these Spa-related methods are truly _just_ convenience methods.

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko yes. If you use UseStaticFile you have to include evey script tag that need to run angular app in your cshtml view or page. AddSpaStaticFiles or UseSpa just make our life easier :)

Answer (score 44):

1. **UseStaticFiles** serves files from wwwroot but it can be changed.
2. **UseSpaStaticFiles** does a similar thing but it requires ISpaStaticFileProvider to be registered. If **app.ApplicationServices.GetService<ISpaStaticFileProvider>()** returns null, then you will get an exception.

```
throw new InvalidOperationException($"To use {nameof(UseSpaStaticFiles)}, you must " +
                    $"first register an {nameof(ISpaStaticFileProvider)} in the service provider, typically " +
                    $"by calling services.{nameof(AddSpaStaticFiles)}.");
```

So you need to call **app.AddSpaStaticFiles()** to register default **ISpaStaticFileProvider**

3. **UseSpa** does two things. Rewrites all requests to the default page and tries to configure static files serving. On the contrary to **UseSpaStaticFiles** it does not throw an exception but just falls back to wwwroot folder.

Actually UseSpaStaticFiles and UseSpa both internally call the same method UseSpaStaticFilesInternal but with a different value for the 3rd parameter which is **allowFallbackOnServingWebRootFiles**. That is the reason why UseSpaStaticFiles throws an exception if no ISpaStaticFileProvider was registered it simply does not allow to fall back  to wwwroot.

**BTW** if **UseSpa** falls back to wwwroot internally it calls old good **app.UseStaticFiles(staticFileOptions);**

Links to github sources:

1. [SpaDefaultMiddleware](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Middleware/Spa/SpaServices.Extensions/src/SpaDefaultPageMiddleware.cs)
2. [SpaStaticFilesExtensions](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Middleware/Spa/SpaServices.Extensions/src/StaticFiles/SpaStaticFilesExtensions.cs)

Comment: So in theory can I get rid of UseSpaStaticFiles and use the UseSpa method alone ? I tried this but its ONLY working when i use both UseSpaStaticFiles and UseSpa together... Im finding it confusing...Also if UseSpaStaticFiles configures the output folder of spa for static file serving then why is the page not loading unless I call UseSpa ? Sorry I find this very confusing. (using netcore3.1)

Comment: @ArunKumarA.J point 3 is critical if you're using angular routing.  The links angular usees need to be sent back to /index.html.  That happens with UseSpa when it does the re-write for anything that does not match an endpoint.

Comment: This answer is better

Answer (score 34):

I've done a deep-dive into how this works recently and I thought I'd explain in detail here, because I don't think it's that well documented.  I've investigated how it works with Visual Studio's React template, but it'll work similarly for other SPA frameworks too.

An important point to understand is that, perhaps unlike a more traditional ASP.NET web application: **the way your ASP.NET SPA site runs in development is *radically* different to how it runs in production.**

The above is very important to remember because much of the internal implementation of this stuff only applies in production, when you're not routing requests through to a Webpack development webserver.  Most of the relevant ASP.NET SPA code is located at [this location](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/c85baf8db0c72ae8e68643029d514b2e737c9fae/src/Middleware/Spa/SpaServices.Extensions/src) in the source repo, which I'll be referencing occasionally below.  If you want to really dig into the implementation, look there.

**IMPORTANT UPDATE:**
With .NET 6, Microsoft have completely flipped how this works and now put the Webpack/Vite/whatever SPA dev server in front of the ASP.NET dev server.  Frankly, this irrirtates me and I don't like what they've done.  I was perfectly happy with the proxying method before.  That code is still there, but presumably they will gradually stop supporting it.  This sucks.  Whatever.  I'll leave the guide below, but it applies to the recommended .NET 5 approach, not the .NET 6 one.

## How SPA works in ASP.NET

So, to go through the various SPA calls in the order in which they're called by default in the template:

```
// In production, the React files will be served from this directory
services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration => {
    configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
});
```

The comment is slightly misleading, as I'll explain below.  This is called in `ConfigureServices`, and [adds in](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c85baf8db0c72ae8e68643029d514b2e737c9fae/src/Middleware/Spa/SpaServices.Extensions/src/StaticFiles/SpaStaticFilesExtensions.cs#L23) the `DefaultSpaStaticFileProvider` as an `ISpaStaticFileProvider` for DI.  This is required if you're going to call `UseSpaStaticFiles` later on (which you probably are).  `RootPath` is specified here (see later on for what it does).  Next (remaining calls are made in `Configure`):

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

This is good old `UseStaticFiles`, tried-and-tested way of serving static files from the `wwwroot` directory.  This is called before the others, meaning that if a requested path exists in `wwwroot`, it will be served immediately from there, and not looked for in the SPA directory (which is `ClientApp/public` by default *during development*, or `ClientApp/build` by default *during production* - see 'Where do the static assets get served from?' below).  If it doesn't exist there, it will fall through to the next middleware, which is:

```
app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
```

This is similar to `app.UseStaticFiles`, but serves static files from a different directory from `wwwroot` - your 'SPA' directory, which defaults to `ClientApp`.  **However**, although it can technically work during development, it is only intended to do anything during *production*.  It looks in the above-mentioned `RootPath` directory - something like `ClientApp/build` - and tries to serve files from there if they exist.  This directory will exist in a published production site, and will contain the SPA content copied from `ClientApp/public`, and also what was generated by Webpack.  However, even though `UseSpaStaticFiles` is still registered when the site's running in development, it will probably fall through, because `ClientApp/build` *doesn't exist during development*.  Why not?  If you publish your app, the `ClientApp/build` directory will indeed be created under your project's root directory.  But the SPA templates rely on it being deleted during development, because when you run `app.UseSpa` later on, it eventually runs `npm run start`, which (if you look in `package.json`) will run something like:

```
"start": "rimraf ./build && react-scripts start",
```

Notice the destruction of the `build` directory.  `UseSpaStaticFiles` is relying on a `npm` script being triggered by a later piece of middleware to delete the `build` directory and effectively stop it from hijacking the pipeline during development!  If you manually restore that `build` directory after starting the site, this middleware *will* serve files from it even during development.  Rather Heath Robinson.  As I mentioned above, the comment about React files being served from this directory 'in Production' is slightly misleading because, well, they'll be served from here during development too.  It's just that there is an assumption that this directory won't exist during development.  Why they didn't just put something like this in the template I'm not sure:

```
if (!env.IsDevelopment()) {
    app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
}
```

And indeed I'd recommend you put that `if` clause in so you're not relying on `build` being deleted from the filesystem.

*UPDATE:* I've just noticed that this middleware isn't quite as odd as I'd first thought.  The `DefaultSpaStaticFileProvider` [actually checks](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c85baf8db0c72ae8e68643029d514b2e737c9fae/src/Middleware/Spa/SpaServices.Extensions/src/StaticFiles/DefaultSpaStaticFileProvider.cs#L42) to see whether `ClientApp/build` exists upon instantiation, and if it doesn't, it doesn't create a file provider, meaning that this will reliably fall through during development when `ClientApp/build` doesn't exist, even if you restore the directory later.  Except that my above description of the behaviour still applies the first time you run the site after publishing, because it's still true that on the first run, `ClientApp/build` will exist, so this check is a bit of a questionable way of detecting whether static files should never be served (like in a dev environment proxying through to an internal Webpack dev server) or not.  I still think my above wrapping of `UseSpaStaticFiles` in a clause along the lines of `if (!env.IsDevelopment()) { ... }` is a more reliable and simpler way to do it, and I'm puzzled that they didn't take that approach.

But anyway, this firmware is intended to fall through 100% of the time during development, because the directory should be deleted when the request is made to ASP.NET, to the final middleware:

```
app.UseSpa(spa => {
    //spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
    // ^ as this is only used in development, it's misleading to put it here.  I've moved
    // it inside the following 'if' clause.

    if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
        spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

        // This is called for the React SPA template, but beneath the surface it, like all
        // similar development server proxies, calls
        // 'SpaProxyingExtensions.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer', which causes all
        // requests to be routed through to a Webpack development server for React, once
        // it's configured and started that server.
        spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
    }
});
```

This ['catch-all' middleware](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c85baf8db0c72ae8e68643029d514b2e737c9fae/src/Middleware/Spa/SpaServices.Extensions/src/SpaApplicationBuilderExtensions.cs#L28) rewrites all requests to the 'default page' for the SPA framework you're using, which is determined by `spa.Options.DefaultPage`, which [defaults to](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c85baf8db0c72ae8e68643029d514b2e737c9fae/src/Middleware/Spa/SpaServices.Extensions/src/SpaOptions.cs#L15) `/index.html`.  So all requests will by default render `/index.html` *during production*, allowing the client app to always load its page and deal appropriately with requests to different URLs.

However, [this middleware](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c85baf8db0c72ae8e68643029d514b2e737c9fae/src/Middleware/Spa/SpaServices.Extensions/src/SpaDefaultPageMiddleware.cs#L33) is NOT intended to get hit *during development*, because of what's inside the above `if (env.IsDevelopment()) { ... }` clause.  That `UseReactDevelopmentServer` (or whatever eventually calls `UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer`, or maybe a direct call to `UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer`) adds a terminal middleware that proxies all requests to a Webpack development server, and actually prevents requests from going through to the `UseSpa` middleware.  So, during production, this middleware runs and acts as a "catch-all" to render `index.html`.  But during development, it is *not* indended to run at all, and requests should be intercepted first by a proxying middleware that forwards to a Webpack development server and returns its responses back.  The Webpack development server is started in the working directory specified by `spa.Options.SourcePath`, so it will serve `ClientApp/public/index.html` as the catch-all webpage *during development* (`/public/`???  See below.)  The `spa.Options.SourcePath` option is not used during production.

### Where do the static assets get served from?

Take a given request for a file `/logo.png`.  `wwwroot` will first be checked, and if it exists there, it will be served.  During *production*, `ClientApp/build` will then be checked for the file, as that was the path configured in `services.AddSpaStaticFiles`.  During *development*, however, this path is effectively not checked (it is, but it should always have been deleted before development starts; see above), and the path that will get checked for static assets instead is `ClientApp/public` in your project's root directory.  This is because the request will be proxied through to an internal Webpack development server.  The Webpack development server serves both dynamically-generated Webpack assets, but also static assets like `/logo.png`, from its "static directory" option, which [defaults to `public`](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/d576068ceb017eebbfa7481b208d751f0452a709/lib/Server.js#L410).  Since the server was started in the `ClientApp` working directory (thanks to the `spa.Options.SourcePath` option), it will try to serve static assets from `ClientApp/public`.

### In summary - execution flow

Basically, ASP.NET's SPA methods are trying to roughly emulate at *production* what the Webpack development server does at *development* - serve static assets first (although ASP.NET also tries `wwwroot` first, which the Webpack dev server obviously doesn't do), then fall through to a default `index.html` for the SPA app (the Webpack dev server doesn't do this by default, but things like `react-scripts` have a default setup which adds a plugin causing this to happen).

However, at *development*, ASP.NET actually *does* proxy requests through to that Webpack dev server, so its SPA middleware is basically meant to get bypassed.  Here's a summary of the intended flow in both cases:

**Production**:

```
Request
-> Check in /wwwroot
-> Check in /ClientApp/build
-> Rewrite request path to /index.html and serve that from /ClientApp/build
```

**Development**:

```
Request
-> Check in /wwwroot
-> Proxy through to internal Webpack dev web server, which:
-> ... serves static assets from /ClientApp/public
-> ... serves dynamically-generated Webpack assets from their locations
-> ... failing that, rewrites request path to /index.html and serves that from /ClientApp/public
```

### An additional WTF

Microsoft made a few design decisions I think are a bit questionable with how they did this, but one behaviour makes no sense to me and I have no idea of its use-case, but it's worth mentioning.

`app.UseSpa` ends up [calling `app.UseSpaStaticFilesInternal`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c85baf8db0c72ae8e68643029d514b2e737c9fae/src/Middleware/Spa/SpaServices.Extensions/src/SpaDefaultPageMiddleware.cs#L42) with the `allowFallbackOnServingWebRootFiles` option set to `true`.  The only time that [has an effect](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c85baf8db0c72ae8e68643029d514b2e737c9fae/src/Middleware/Spa/SpaServices.Extensions/src/StaticFiles/SpaStaticFilesExtensions.cs#L131) is if you *didn't* previously add an `ISpaStaticFileProvider` to DI (eg. by calling `services.AddSpaStaticFiles`), and you call `app.UseSpa` anyway.  In that case, instead of throwing an exception, it will serve files from `wwwroot`.  I honestly have no idea what the point of this is.  The template already calls `app.UseStaticFiles` before anything else, so files from `wwwroot` already get served as top priority.  If you remove that, *and* remove `services.AddSpaStaticFiles`, *and* don't call `app.UseSpaStaticFiles` (because that'll throw the exception), then `app.UseSpa` will serve files from `wwwroot`.  If that has a use-case, I don't know what it is.

### Further thoughts

This setup works OK, but the 'on-demand' setup of the Webpack development server seems to [spin up](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c85baf8db0c72ae8e68643029d514b2e737c9fae/src/Middleware/Spa/SpaServices.Extensions/src/ReactDevelopmentServer/ReactDevelopmentServerMiddleware.cs#L65) a ton of node instances, which seems rather inefficient to me.  As suggested under 'Updated development setup' in [this blog](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-core/1525/angular-react-vuejs-svelte-spa-aspnet-core-3) (which also provides some good insights into how this SPA stuff works), it might be a better idea to manually run the Webpack development server (or Angular/React/whatever) at the beginning of your development session, and change the on-demand creation of a dev server (`spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start")`) to [on-demand creation](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c85baf8db0c72ae8e68643029d514b2e737c9fae/src/Middleware/Spa/SpaServices.Extensions/src/Proxying/SpaProxyingExtensions.cs#L56) of a proxy to the existing dev server (`spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200")`), which should avoid spinning up 101 node instances.  This also avoids some unnecessary slowness of rebuilding the JS each time something in the ASP.NET source changes.

Hmm... MS went to so much effort to allow that proxying through to a node-backed Webpack development web server, it would almost be simpler if they just recommended that in production, you deploy a node-based web server to proxy all SPA requests through to.  That would avoid all the extra code which acts differently in production and development.  Oh well, I guess that this way, at least when you get to production, you're not reliant on node.  But you pretty much are at development.  Probably unavoidable given how all the SPA ecosystems are designed to work with node.  When it comes to SPA applications, node has effectively become a necessary build tool, akin to the likes of `gcc`.  You don't need it to run the compiled application, but you sure need it to transpile it from source.  I guess hand-crafting the JavaScript to run in the browser, in this analogy, would be like hand-writing the assembly.  Technically possible, but not really done.

Comment: `spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200")` works soo much better