# How to deploy Angular SPA with ASP.NET Core 3.1 API on IIS?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-core-webapi

Should be simple scenario I imagine; have

1. Angluar 8 SPA
2. ASP .NET Core 3.1 Web API

Want to deploy on Windows Server with IIS have read through: [Host ASP.NET Core on Windows with IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

[image: in-process hosting model]

Want to with reccomended default In-process hosting model

But how to combine the Angular SPA and .net core web api? I can get the web api running fine under a new site in IIS serving files from publish output but where to put my SPA?

- Mix Angular build in with the publish output?
- Create sub application for Web API but IIS then adds an alias so my routes like `api/blah` become `alias/api/blah`
- Use the other hostinmodel and proxy to Kestrel server running on different port?
- Some wwwroot dir to redirect to so navigating to website serves SPA from there?

I see if using the Angular template to create solution it creates a `ClientApps/dist` dir, maybe could recreate the project with that template then dump the Angular build in that dir on deploy (since Angular project developed in separate repo).

```
            // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
            });
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55988045/what-is-the-difference-between-usestaticfiles-usespastaticfiles-and-usespa-in. I think you could use app.usespa to combine your .net core application and angularspa application. Then you can deploy the application to IIS via web deployement tool. Another way is create a sub-application inside your IIS side. Then rewrite any request to api/blah to alias/api/blah

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seeing this question is already a month old. Hopefully you have found a solution. @JokiesDing comment is pretty much on point.

My approach with development and deployment is to have the SPA application inside the Web API project and utilize `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions`. Here are the steps:

1. Create an Angular Application and put it inside your application directory. For example, I usually create an ClientApp Folder inside the project and place my angular app inside.
   [image: project directory]
2. Install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions` from Nuget
3. Go to your `Startup.cs` and add the extension methods

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   //... whatever you have in your ConfigureServices method...

   //add this
   services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
   {
      configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
   });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    //... whatever you have in your configure method...

    //add this
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    if (!env.IsDevelopment())
    {
       app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
    }


   app.UseSpa(spa =>
   {
     // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA
     // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501
     spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
     if (env.IsDevelopment())
     {
         spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
     }
    });
}
```

5. Bonus! if you don't want to run `npm run start` everytime you build, you can point the webapi to the SPA dev server.

```
 if (env.IsDevelopment())
 {
   spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200");
 }
```

For Reference see this starter template
https://github.com/jasontaylordev/CleanArchitecture

Comment: how to publish it?