IIS port numbers vs VS2022 port numbers
I have downloaded a template from https://github.com/Njabulo240/IdentityHub.  It is using Angular 18, .NET 8 and SQL backend.
My environment is VS2022 and VSCode.  The app runs well in my VS2022 dev environment.  However, when I publish it to my local IIS it doesn't work any more (Local IIS and my VS2022 are in the same machine running Win10).  My localhost is using port 80 and https://localhost is using port 443.  In the application is using ports 4200 and 5296.
Can any one out there "EDUCATE" me between ports in IIS vs ports in VS2022?
How and what it happens when I published to IIS environment?
This issue causes me a lot troubles since there is not many explanations when almost no one talked about publishing app to IIS.
Thanks.
Appreciate for any input.

anything that wants to publish a service has to have a port allocated to serve it on, and every service has to have different ports else they clash. IIS (and websites on the web) are typically 80/443. Whereas VS uses some range of ports hopefully unused elsewhere. Its pretty much irrelevant so long as you try and access it on the correct port.

However, when I publish it to my local IIS it doesn't work any more this however is unlikely to be related to ports... you need to look in your logs to see why its failing... assuming its not showing you the error on the screen.

I did change ports 5296 and 4200 to 80 and 443 and published it. It doesn't work.  Also, I tried change ports in IIS to 80 and 443 to 5296 and 4200 and it still doesn't work. This, I assumed there is no clashing between port numbers any more.  Since I changed ports accordingly, WHY It works in VS2022 but not in the IIS?  This is the question I wonder a long time.

You don't need to touch the ports... the ports in VS are for when you run in VS, IIS has its own ports configured. You might have broken it by changing it. Anyway, please clarify what "doesn't work" means... why do you think its port related?

When I start the app from IIS, the angular page displays propery.  When I tried to do register or login (to access the .net api) and it won't do anything (but it accesses in the VS2022).  The reason I think it is relate to ports because in IIS is using port different from the app (the port number is hardcoded in the application in the environment and also in the appsetttings.json file.

It really depends how your Angular/.NET app is intended to be deployed, and how you have configured it. Some people run Angular under IIS and .NET under Kestral. Ports might be a part of the equation, but you need to fully understand how the whole app is being deployed and how each part talks to each other. And without providing us with those details we aren't really in a position to assist.

I put the link in my question.  I hope some one EDUCATE me so that I won't be in dark room any more. Thanks.

The link doesn't explain how you are hosting it in IIS... and the topic is too big for a single question, you need to research further. For example read some questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62055847/how-to-deploy-angular-spa-with-asp-net-core-3-1-api-on-iis

I can explain how I published to IIS or I can give you screen shots.  The topic is too big in general, however, if you download the code and run in VS2022 and published it to IIS then you will know.  After that you can discuss or EDUCATE me more.  Without the code, any thing can go wrong. Thank you.

There are 3 places in the app. 1: appsettings.json, 2: Enviroment (appUrl), 3: Account Service that call backend.

I am surprised that you did not encounter the common 500.19 error message or discuss the ASP.NET Core module settings in your previous explanation. If these obstacles were not encountered, it is possible that you may not have followed the correct guide for publishing the web application from source code. It is important to note that free education isn't always offered, so it may be beneficial to consider hiring a mentor from a freelancer site yourself.

I did not encounter 500.19 but 500.30.  However, I resolved the 500.30 issue.  How did you get it?

I did follow the instructions per Microsoft web site (VS2022).  If there are any issues, it should give me errors in VS2022 or test enviroment.  If everything is working in testing environment, should it be working in production too? Thanks.

No, IIS is configured quite differently to VS.

I cannot say bad word here but it looks like VS is the initial test environment.  IIS is another test environment as well since it cannot be working if it works in VS.  It is too bad I can not debugger in the IIS to find the root cause.

You can connect a debugger to IIS... "connect to process"

You can try to configure failed request tracing for the deployed application, which will generate detailed message logs. I think this should help locate the problem. Just refer to  this official doc: Using Failed Request Tracing rules to troubleshoot Application Request Routing.

It is way over my head now.:(

follow the instructions, the tracing folder is always empty. It looks there is issue on Angular side.

still think the port number hard coded in the app causes issues in iis environment.  Need to confirm buy guru please.

remove hard code port number and add proxy config to the project.  The proxy will correct url and port number in the IIS.  for example instead of calling service this.url/api/update/amployee, I need just put /api/update/employe The proxy will pad url for me.
Hard code is the bad practice
