# Adding SPA to .NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, single-page-application

I want to add a separately developed Vue-based SPA to a .NET Core Web API project.

How do I bundle my Vue app with the Web API project?

Comment: This template creates a Vue client + a web API, maybe you could try to create one of these, see how it's configured to work and do the same in yours. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alexandredotnet.netcorevuejs

Comment: @devcrp Your hint led me to the link provided in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The question has already been answered, though with a different focus, here: [What is the difference between UseStaticFiles, UseSpaStaticFiles, and UseSpa in ASP.NET Core 2.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55988045/what-is-the-difference-between-usestaticfiles-usespastaticfiles-and-usespa-in)