# project is blank on refresh with asp.net core and react js

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, asp.net-core

We are making a project with asp.net core and react js, and the file structure is like this

[image: project file structure image]

`ReactApp` is where I put my react codes and `wwwroot` is where I put my build folder. When we run on visual studio, page shows up by calling wwwroot folder but when we refresh the page, it goes blank. I think it's because it's calling the `ClientApp` folder somehow which doesn't have any codes in it and not the `wwwroot` folder anymore. Is there any ways to prevent this from happening ? This is the codes from startup.cs file

```cs
using AssestManagement.Common;
using AssestManagement.IServices;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.ReactDevelopmentServer;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace AssestManagement
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDirectoryBrowser();
            services.AddMvc()
            .AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();
            services.AddSession(options => {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });
            services.AddCors();
            
            services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
            Global.ConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("SmilaxGlobal_SSHR_OLS");
            services.AddScoped<IStatusService, StatusService>();
            services.AddScoped<ITypeService, TypeService>();
            services.AddScoped<IAssetColumnService, AssetColumnService>();
            services.AddScoped<ICategoryService, CategoryService>();
            services.AddScoped<IBrandService, BrandService>();
            services.AddScoped<IAssetService, AssetService>();
            services.AddScoped<IAssetTagService,AssetTagService > ();
            services.AddScoped<ISupplierService, SupplierService>();
            services.AddScoped<ILocationService, LocationService>();
            services.AddScoped<IBranchService, BranchService>();
            services.AddScoped<ICompanyService, CompanyService>();
            services.AddScoped<ISectionService, SectionService>();
            services.AddScoped<IDepartmentService, DepartmentService>();
            services.AddScoped<ILoginService, LoginService>();
            services.AddScoped<IRequestableService, RequestableService>();
            services.AddScoped<IEmployeeService, EmployeeService>();
            services.AddScoped<IAssetLocationService, AssetLocationService>();
            services.AddControllers();


            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                    builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader());
               
            });

            services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
           
            // In production, the React files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build"; //ClientApp/build
            });
        }

        
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
           


            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
               
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
          
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();


            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
            {
                ServeUnknownFileTypes = true,
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot\Uploads")),//
                RequestPath = new PathString("/Uploads")
            });
            app.UseDirectoryBrowser(new DirectoryBrowserOptions()
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
            Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot\Uploads")),//wwwroot\
                RequestPath = new PathString("/Uploads")
            });
            //app.RunIISPipeline();
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();
          
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp"; //ClientApp

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to use F12 developer tools to check whether there have any error and whether the page resource load success? Besides, if possible, can you post the related configuration method in the Startup.cs file? perhaps you have changed the root path.

Comment: if you are setting up react with .NET, perhaps, look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64092509/the-default-asp-net-core-react-template-in-visual-studio-2019-doesnt-work . that question also talks about folder structure and spa settings in dot net core. Also, yes, startup file details are required to see how things are configured in your app.

Comment: @ZhiLv I don't see any erros on console when the page goes blank, and I added the codes from startup.cs file, would you mind checking it ?

Comment: @Jay I'll check it out, I added the codes from startup.cs file as well.

Comment: The configuration code looks okay. Which version of Browser are you using? As far as I know, if we are using the old version of Browser, such as IE browser, if the application not add the polyfill, it will show a blank page. Besides, try to use F12 developer tools Network tools to check whether the request is success and the related resource is loaded or not?