# Vue component is not loading for Vue.Js + ASP.Net Core MVC application

Tags: asp.net-core

I am migrating my ASP.NET MVC + Vue.js application to ASP.NET core. The existing application is running fine without having problem. We have followed existing code structure and java scripts libraries to migrate from .Net framework to .Net core. The problem is when we run the new application then the Vue components are not loading.

Here is the code snippet,

**home.js (initialize Vue component)**

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";

window.removeA = function(arr) {
    var what, a = arguments, L = a.length, ax;
    while (L > 1 && arr.length) {
        what = a[--L];
        while ((ax= arr.indexOf(what)) !== -1) {
            arr.splice(ax, 1);
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
new Vue({
  el : '#calendar',
  render: h => h(App),
  template : '<App/>',
  components : {
    App
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

**App.vue for Vue template**

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<template>
    <div>
        <Header :user="user"
                :canAdd="canAdd"
                :newCount="newCount"
                :revCount="revCount"
                @mallingEvent="getThisMonth"></Header>
        <loading v-if="loading"></loading>
        <div class="center-wr">test search
            <div class="filter-wr">
                <div class="filter-title">
                    <Search @search="search" />
                </div>
                <Filter-Item v-if="dictionary && dictionary.filters"
                             :filter="dictionary.filters"
                             :title="'Media plan level'"
                             v-on:give-filter="filterEventsMedia"
                             v-on:give-Clearfilter="ClearFilterMedia">
                    <template #filterIcon>
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="14" height="14" viewBox="0 0 14 14" fill="none">
                            <path d="M12.4444 14H1.55556C0.696446 14 0 13.3036 0 12.4444V1.55556C0 0.696445 0.696446 0 1.55556 0H12.4444C13.3036 0 14 0.696445 14 1.55556V12.4444C14 13.3036 13.3036 14 12.4444 14Z" fill="#C5D6E7" />
                            <path class="not-hover" opacity="0.5" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M8.13665 10.6497H10.1366V6.46162H8.13665V10.6497ZM3.35034 10.6496H5.35034V3.11118H3.35034V10.6496Z" fill="#FDFDFE" />
                        </svg>
                    </template>
                </Filter-Item>
                <Filter-Item v-if="dictionary && dictionary.types"
                             :filter="dictionary.types"
                             :title="'Task type'"
                             v-on:give-filter="filterEventsType"
                             v-on:give-Clearfilter="ClearFilterType">
                    <template #filterIcon>
                        <svg width="17" height="16" viewBox="0 0 17 16" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <path d="M8.5 0L11.1265 5.26604L17 6.11567L12.75 10.2124L13.753 16L8.5 13.266L3.247 16L4.25 10.2124L0 6.11567L5.8735 5.26604L8.5 0Z" fill="#C5D6E7" />
                        </svg>
                    </template>
                </Filter-Item>
            </div>
            <div class="search-block" v-if="searchFlag">                
                <div class="search-content" v-if="searchItems.length > 0">
                    <div class="search-content-top">
                        <div class="search-content-total">{{searchItems.length}} results found:</div>
                        <div class="search-content-btn" @click="backToMedia">
                            Go back to media plan
                            <svg width="6" height="9" viewBox="0 0 6 9" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <path opacity="0.5" d="M0.75 1.25L4.25 4.75L0.75 8.25" stroke="white" stroke-width="1.5" />
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="search-list">
                        <div v-for="(item, index) in searchItems" :key="index" class="search-list-item">
                            <CardList @openInfoPopup="openInfoPopup" @showMore="showMore" :popup="false" :openItems="openItems" :colorTypes="dictionary.types" :item="item" :toggleLoading="toggleLoading" :dictionary="dictionary" :userRole="user.RoleCode" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="search-content noresult" v-else>
                    <div class="noresult-title">No results</div>
                    <div class="noresult-btn" @click="backToMedia">Go back to media plan</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <template v-else>
                <full-calendar :events="eventsData"
                               :dictionary="dictionary"
                               :userRole="user.RoleCode"
                               :canAdd="canAdd"
                               :addAbsolute="addAbsolute"
                               :colorTypes="dictionary.types"
                               v-if="dictionary && dictionary.types"
                               eventsLim="500" firstDay="1" locale="en"
                               @eventClick="eventClick"
                               @dayClick="dayClick"
                               @dayMouseEnter="dayMouseEnter($event)"
                               @changeMonth="monthChange"
                               :formats="dictionary.formats">

                    <template slot="fc-body-card">
                    </template>
                    <template slot="current-card">
                        <CardCurrent :colorTypes="dictionary.types" @eventClick="eventClick" @addEvent="addEvent" :events="eventsData" />
                    </template>

                </full-calendar>
            </template>
            <card :colorTypes="dictionary.types" :item="curentItem" :dictionary="dictionary" :clear="clearCurentItem" :toggleLoading="toggleLoading" :userRole="user.RoleCode" :initApp="initApp" :isLoading="changeLoading"
                  v-if="!!curentItem.id"></card>
            <div class="popup-wr" v-if="currentItemPopup">
                <CardList :popup="true" @openInfoPopup="openInfoPopup" @showMore="showMore" :openItems="openItems" @closeInfoPopup="closeInfoPopup" :colorTypes="dictionary.types" :item="currentItemPopup" :toggleLoading="toggleLoading" :dictionary="dictionary" :userRole="user.RoleCode" />
            </div>

            <mailCard :toggleLoading="toggleLoading" :clear="clearCount" :mail="sendMail"
                      :tMonth="getThisMonth" :nMonth="getNextMonth" :vmail="sendValidatorMail"
                      :count="count" v-if="count != null"></mailCard>
        </div>
        <Footer-block v-if="dictionary"
                      :colorTypes="dictionary.types">

        </Footer-block>

    </div>
</template>

<script>

    import $ from "jquery";
    import Vue from "vue";
    import moment from "moment";
    import Component from "vue-class-component";
    import FullCalendar from "./fullCalendar/fullCalendar.vue";
    import Loading from "./components/loading.vue";


    import Card from "./card/card.vue";
    import CardList from "./card/cardList.vue";
    import MailCard from "./card/mailCard.vue";
    import AddEvent from "./addEvent.vue";
    import Header from './components/header.vue';
    import Footer from './components/footer.vue'
    import FilterItem from './components/filter-Item.vue'
    import CardCurrent from './components/card-current.vue'
    import Search from './components/search.vue'

    import { DataService } from "./service";
    import BusEvent from './fullCalendar/components/busEvent'

    @Component({
        components: {
            FullCalendar,
            Card,
            MailCard,
            AddEvent,
            Loading,
            Header,
            'Footer-block': Footer,
            FilterItem,
            CardCurrent,
            Search,
            CardList
        }
    })

    export default class App extends Vue {
        //Thech
        isLoading = true;
        service = null;
        user = {};
        canAdd = false;
        openItems = [];
        currentItemPopup = null;

        //Filters
        selectedFilterMedia = [];
        selectedFilterType = [];
        selectedFilterStatuses = [];
        selectedFilterModes = [];
        selectedFilterChannel = [];
        selectedMediaPlan = "Media plan level"

        //Event data
        fcEvents = null;
        eventsAll = [];
        dictionary = null;
        curentItem = {};
        searchItems = [];
        searchItemsAll = [];
        searchFlag = false;

        newCount = 0;
        revCount = 0;
        //Creating
        sDate = null;
        eDate = null;
        sObj = null;
        selection = false;

        //Mailing
        count = null;
        date = null;

        selectedFilter = { Id: 0, Title: "ALL" };
        preSelectedFilterId = 0;

        //state
        searchText = '';
        addAbsolute = false;

        mounted() {

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('body').on('click', '.switch-gcts-inner', function (e) {
                    if ($(e.target).parents('.btn-box').length > 0 || $(e.target).hasClass('btn-box')) { }
                    else {
                        $('.switch-gcts-inner').removeClass('open');
                        $(this).addClass('open');
                    }
                });

                $('body').on('click', function (e) {
                    if ($(e.target).parents('.switch-gcts-inner').length > 0 || $(e.target).hasClass('switch-gcts-inner')) {

                    } else {

                        $('.switch-gcts-inner').removeClass('open');
                    }

                });

                $('body').on('click', function (e) {
                    if ($(e.target).parents('.switch-gcts-trend-select-item').length > 0 || ($(e.target).parents('.switch-gcts-trend-select').length > 0)) {
                    }
                    else
                        $('.switch-gcts-trend-select-item').removeClass('open');
                });
            });
            this.service = new DataService();

            this.initUserData();
        }
        showMore(id) {
            if(this.openItems.includes(id)) {
                this.openItems = this.openItems.filter(item => item !== id);
            }
            else {
                this.openItems.push(id);
            }
        }
        initUserData() {
            this.isLoading = true;
            Promise.all([
                this.service.getUser()])

                .then((result) => {
                    this.user = result[0].user;
                    this.canAdd = result[0].canAdd;

                    this.dictionary = result[0].Dictionaries;

                    this.fcEvents = [];
                    this.eventsAll = [];
                    var currMonth = new Date();
                    this.newCount = 0;
                    this.revCount = 0;
                    if(this.getCookie("ptf_search").length > 0) {
                        this.searchTimeOut(this.getCookie("ptf_search"))
                    }
                    else {
                        this.isLoading = false;
                    }
                });
        }
        initApp(month, year) {
            this.isLoading = true;
            Promise.all([
                this.service.getUser(),
                this.service.getData(month, year)])

                .then((result) => {
                     this.user = result[0].user;
                     this.canAdd = result[0].canAdd;
                     this.dictionary = result[0].Dictionaries;
                    this.fcEvents = [];
                    this.eventsAll = [];
                    var currMonth = new Date();
                    this.newCount = 0;
                    this.revCount = 0;
                    result[0].Activities.map((item) => {

                        var start = moment(item.start)._d;


                        var needCalcCount = (month - 1 == start.getMonth()) && (year == start.getFullYear());


                        if (needCalcCount && (item.needAdmin || item.needTrade || item.needValidate || item.needLegal) && (!item.returned)) this.newCount++;
                        if (needCalcCount && (this.user.RoleCode == 'admin') && (item.returned)) this.revCount++;

                        item.start = moment(item.start).format();
                        item.end = moment(item.end).format();
                        item.endActual = moment(item.endActual).format();
                        this.fcEvents.push(item);
                        this.eventsAll.push(item);


                    });
                    this.applyFilter();
                    this.dictionary = result[1].Dictionaries;
                    this.isLoading = false;
                });
        }
        changeLoading(flag) {
            this.isLoading = flag;
        }
        filterEventsMedia(item) {
            if (this.selectedFilterMedia.indexOf(item.id) == -1)
                this.selectedFilterMedia.push(item.id);
            else
                this.selectedFilterMedia = window.removeA(this.selectedFilterMedia, item.id);
            this.applyFilter()
        }
        ClearFilterMedia() {
            this.selectedFilterMedia = []
            this.applyFilter()
        }
        filterEventsType(item) {
            if (this.selectedFilterType.indexOf(item.id) == -1)
                this.selectedFilterType.push(item.id);
            else
                this.selectedFilterType = window.removeA(this.selectedFilterType, item.id);
            this.applyFilter()
        }
        ClearFilterType() {
            this.selectedFilterType = []
            this.applyFilter()
        }
        filterEventsChannel(item) {
            //this.selectedFilterChannel.push(item.id)
            if (this.selectedFilterChannel.indexOf(item.id) == -1)
                this.selectedFilterChannel.push(item.id);
            else
                this.selectedFilterChannel = window.removeA(this.selectedFilterChannel, item.id);
            this.applyFilter()
        }
        ClearFilterChannel() {
            this.selectedFilterChannel = []
            this.applyFilter()
        }
        monthChange(date) {
            this.initApp(date.getMonth() + 1, date.getFullYear());
        }
        filterEventsStatuses(item) {
            //this.selectedFilterStatuses.push(item.id)
            if (this.selectedFilterStatuses.indexOf(item.id) == -1)
                this.selectedFilterStatuses.push(item.id);
            else
                this.selectedFilterStatuses = window.removeA(this.selectedFilterStatuses, item.id);
            this.applyFilter()
        }
        ClearFilterStatuses() {
            this.selectedFilterStatuses = []
            this.applyFilter()
        }
        filterEventsModes(item) {
            //this.selectedFilterStatuses.push(item.id)
            if (this.selectedFilterModes.indexOf(item.id) == -1)
                this.selectedFilterModes.push(item.id);
            else
                this.selectedFilterModes = window.removeA(this.selectedFilterModes, item.id);
            this.applyFilter()
        }
        ClearFilterModes() {
            this.selectedFilterModes = []
            this.applyFilter()
        }
        searchTimeOut(value) {
                if (this.timer) {
                    clearTimeout(this.timer);
                    this.timer = null;
                }
                this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
                    this.isLoading = true;
                    if (value.length > 0) {
                        Promise.all([
                            this.service.getUser(),
                            this.service.searchItems(value)])

                            .then((result) => {
                                this.searchItemsAll = result[0];
                                this.searchFlag = true;
                                this.isLoading = false;
                                this.applyFilter();
                            });
                    }
                    else {
                        this.searchItems = [];
                        this.searchFlag = false;
                        this.isLoading = false;
                    }
                }, 500);
        }
        search(event) {
            this.searchText = event.target.value;
            document.cookie = "ptf_search="+this.searchText;
            this.searchTimeOut(this.searchText);
        }
        backToMedia() {
            this.searchText = '';
            document.cookie = "ptf_search="+this.searchText;
            this.searchItems = [];
            this.searchFlag = false;
            BusEvent.$emit('backToMedia');
        }
        applyFilter() {
            if (!this.dictionary) return;
            let _scope = this;
            this.fcEvents = this.eventsAll.filter((item) => {
                return (

                    (item.levelIds.filter((item2) => _scope.selectedFilterMedia.indexOf(item2) !== -1).length > 0 || _scope.selectedFilterMedia.length === 0)
                    &&
                    (item.taskTypeIds.filter((item2) => _scope.selectedFilterType.indexOf(item2) !== -1).length > 0 || _scope.selectedFilterType.length === 0)
                    &&
                    (item.channelIds.filter((item2) => _scope.selectedFilterChannel.indexOf(item2) !== -1).length > 0 || _scope.selectedFilterChannel.length === 0)
                    &&
                    (this.selectedFilterModes.indexOf(item.taskModeId) !== -1 || _scope.selectedFilterModes.length === 0)
                    &&
                    (this.selectedFilterStatuses.indexOf(item.statusId) !== -1 || _scope.selectedFilterStatuses.length === 0)
                )
            });
            this.searchItems = this.searchItemsAll.filter((item) => {
                return (

                    (item.LevelIds.filter((item2) => _scope.selectedFilterMedia.indexOf(item2) !== -1).length > 0 || _scope.selectedFilterMedia.length === 0)
                    &&
                    (item.taskTypeIds.filter((item2) => _scope.selectedFilterType.indexOf(item2) !== -1).length > 0 || _scope.selectedFilterType.length === 0)
                    &&
                    (item.Channels.filter((item2) => _scope.selectedFilterChannel.indexOf(item2) !== -1).length > 0 || _scope.selectedFilterChannel.length === 0)
                    &&
                    (this.selectedFilterModes.indexOf(item.TaskModeId) !== -1 || _scope.selectedFilterModes.length === 0)
                    &&
                    (this.selectedFilterStatuses.indexOf(item.TaskStatusId) !== -1 || _scope.selectedFilterStatuses.length === 0)
                )
            });
        }
        preSelectFilter(val) {
            this.preSelectedFilterId = val;
        }
        toggleLoading(val) {
            this.isLoading = val;
        }
        get loading() {
            return this.isLoading;
        }
        get eventsData() {
            if (this.fcEvents == null) {
                return [];
            }
            else {
                return this.fcEvents;
            }
        }
        clearCurentItem() {
            this.curentItem = {};
        }
        clearNewItem() {
            this.newItem = null;
        }
        eventClick(obj) {
            this.curentItem = obj;
        }
        dayMouseEnter(e) {

            if (this.selection) {
                this.fcEvents[this.fcEvents.length - 1].end = moment(e).format();
            }
        }
        addEvent(day) {
            if (confirm('Create new Activity?')) {
                window.location.href = `/createActivity?sDate=${day}&eDate=${day}&returnURL=create`;
            }
        }
        dayClick(obj) {
            if (this.canAdd) {
                this.addAbsolute = true;
                if (this.sDate === null) {
                    this.sObj = obj;

                    this.sDate = obj;///moment(obj).format();
                    let event = {
                        title: "New",
                        start: this.sDate,
                        end: this.sDate,
                        cssClass: "status-1",
                        isShow: true,
                        cellIndex: 1
                    };
                    this.fcEvents.push(event);
                    this.selection = true;

                    this.sDate = obj;
                }
                else {
                    this.eDate = obj;//moment(obj).format();

                    if (obj >= this.sObj) {
                        if (confirm('Create new Activity?')) {
                            this.addAbsolute = false;
                            this.selection = false;
                            window.location.href = `/createActivity?sDate=${this.sDate}&eDate=${this.eDate}&returnURL=create`;
                        }
                        else {
                            this.addAbsolute = false;
                            this.clearDates();
                        }
                    } else {
                        this.addAbsolute = false;
                        this.clearDates();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        clearDates() {
            this.selection = false;
            this.fcEvents.splice(this.fcEvents.length - 1, 1);
            this.sDate = null;
            this.eDate = null;
        }
        getCookie(name) {

            var matches = document.cookie.match(new RegExp(
                "(?:^|; )" + name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1') + "=([^;]*)"
            ));
            return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : "";

        }
        getThisMonth() {

            this.date = new Date();
            this.toggleLoading(true);


            this.service
                .getCount(this.date)
                .then((data) => {
                    this.count = data;
                    this.toggleLoading(false);
                });
        }

        getNextMonth() {
            this.date = new Date((new Date()).setMonth(new Date().getMonth() + 1));
            this.toggleLoading(true);

            this.service
                .getCount(this.date)
                .then((data) => {
                    this.count = data;
                    this.toggleLoading(false);
                });
        }
        sendValidatorMail() {
            this.toggleLoading(true);
            this.service
                .sendValidatorMail(this.date)
                .then((data) => {
                    if (data == true)
                        this.clearCount();
                    else
                        this.count = -1;
                    this.initApp();
                });
        }
        sendMail() {
            this.toggleLoading(true);
            this.service
                .sendMail(this.date)
                .then((data) => {
                    if (data == true)
                        this.clearCount();
                    else
                        this.count = -1;


                    this.initApp();
                });
        }

        clearCount() {
            this.count = null;
        }

        openInfoPopup(item) {
            this.currentItemPopup = item;
            document.body.classList.add('remove-scroll')
        }

        closeInfoPopup() {
            this.currentItemPopup = null;
            document.body.classList.remove('remove-scroll')
        }

    }
</script>
```

**index.cshtml for consuming the Vue**

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    var userRole = (string)ViewBag.userRole;
}
@model Bs.WebApp.Model.HomeVM

<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-content nopadding">
            <div id="calendar">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts{
    <script src="~/assets/js/lib/fullcalendar.js"></script>
    <script src="~/assets/js/pages/home/home.js"></script>

}

<link href="~/assets/css/common.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Is there any error in the console?

Comment: @jishansiddique No there is no error in the console.

Comment: @jishansiddique after updating the data mapping properties, now few component is loading but at the same time I am also getting Type Script error in the Console. 
[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to server intercepting the route and not passing it to the client. The symptom would be that the client app works until the page is refreshed or accessed with a direct url.

I solved this by adding a fallback path to the endpoint configuration:

```
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("/index.html");
    });
```

See my answer to this question:
[Is there a way to serve vue.js statc file with .NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65357402/is-there-a-way-to-serve-vue-js-statc-file-with-net-mvc/69230595#69230595)