# What angular versions are compatible with AspNetCore SpaServices?

Tags: angular, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

We are converting an old application that uses .net framework and angular 1.7 to .net core 2.1. My first step is to convert to .net core and startup the old angular code with it.

I have found an example in .net core using services.AddSpaStaticFiles, app.UseSpaStaticFiles, spa.UseAngularCliServer.

I have got the example running, but how do I now link the startup to the old application, and would that even be possible? Are these extensions in Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices even compatible with this very old angular version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to differentiate between Angular and AngularJS when reading the docs and examples. The old versions (1.X) are commonly referred to as AngularJS while the new versions (2.X) are referred to as Angular.

It is possible to run any frontend using any version of .NET Core, but the default expansion methods might not be suited to handle every single case, so you might have to write your custom middleware that will handle different stuff for you. Sadly, I have no experience with AngularJS so I don't know if the default pipeline will work correctly or what adjustments need to be done. I would assume that AngularJS doesn't use the Angular CLI (but please do double-check on that) so `UseAngularCliServer` is out of the equation.

You can refer to on the basics of how the extension methods work to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56977859/4550158) Stack Overflow answer.

What you need to do will highly depend on your SPA application, but the basics would be:

- Letting the application know it should serve some file as a "default" (e.g. `index.html`)
- Lettng the application know that your SPA will use some resources that should be served as well (e.g. scripts, images, js files,  etc.)
- Letting the application know that there is "internal" routing in the SPA and it shouldn't try to load different resources when those routes are requested (e.g. do not return 404 on sub-routes).

An example guide I found (using .NET Core 2.0, but you should be able to adapt to 2.1) is [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51378.asp-net-core-single-page-application-with-angularjs.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The contents of the following NuGet packages have all been unnecessary since ASP.NET Core 2.1, and so are now being marked as obsolete:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices
Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices
```

[[Announcement] Obsoleting Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices and Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/12890)