# How to run a VueJS application in ASP.NET core using NPM

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, vuejs3

I Have a blank asp.net core 5 web application and I have used npm to install vue3 and scaffold one of the default setups. It creates a directory for the app in the projects root directory and in the new app folder I set the vue.config.js file build route to the projects wwwroot folder using the following:

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  outputDir: path.resolve(__dirname, "../wwwroot"),
  assetdir: "../wwwroot"
}
```

This works and my npm run build does in fact save to a wwwroot folder however it deletes the current wwwroot folder in visual studio and creates a new wwwroot folder. The problem is the globe next to the wwwroot disappears when it is recreated and it is just a folder icon. Not sure how important that is but strange that happens

I next go into the startup.cs and add

```
        app.UseDefaultFiles(); // Enables default file mapping on the web root.
        app.UseStaticFiles();
```

Now when I go to run this project it loads a blank page but if I go to the url https://localhost:44391/wwwroot/ it loads just a menu with Home and About at the top and if I click home it takes me to https://localhost:44391/ with the correct vue home template. I do have the standard router setup but I have not changed any of that and history mode was set as yes during the vue installation if that matters. I am not sure why this is not working correctly. Do I need to add UseContentRoot() in program.cs or something?

Comment: Have you created an asp.net core project with spa template to have a look.Based on your description, it is not clear what your startup.cs code.You 'd better show steps to reproduce and give the result you want.Generally, we have ClientApp outside of `wwwroot` to put building files , and add spa configs in startup.cs https://stackoverflow.com/a/55989907/10158551

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run asp.net core project with vue application, in your case , your `startup.cs` may refer to below setting:

(Install Package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions` choose Version as 5.x firstly)

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration => { configuration.RootPath = "wwwroot"; });
        services.AddRazorPages();
    }

 
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
      
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        if (!env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
        }

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "wwwroot";
            //if (env.IsDevelopment())
            //{
            //    try
            //    {
            //        spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:1234/");
            //    }
            //    catch
            //    {
            //    }
            //}
        });
    }
}
```