# Using top level route registration doesn't work with UseSpa

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-7.0

I have a .NET 6 SPA project that uses endpoint routing, with the following `Program.cs` code:

```csharp
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
       name: "default",
       pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});


app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:3000");
    }

});

app.Run();
```

This code runs fine, but now I'm updating the project to .NET 7 and I got this warning: `Suggest using top level route registrations instead of UseEndpoints`. I changed the `UseEndpoints` code to this:

```csharp
app.MapControllers();
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

However, this change completely breaks my routing, and calling any API endpoints give me a 404. Navigating to any API endpoint from my browser returns my SPA. If I remove the call to `UseSpa` the routing works fine.

How can I get this to work?

EDIT: I am aware that I can remove `UseSpa` and instead proxy from the other direction, in my frontend project. This seems to be the new recommended approach, as described in this answer [What is the difference between UseStaticFiles, UseSpaStaticFiles, and UseSpa in ASP.NET Core 2.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55988045/what-is-the-difference-between-usestaticfiles-usespastaticfiles-and-usespa-in/73419459#73419459). However I am used to my current setup and I would like to continue to use `UseSpa`. Is that not possible anymore?

Comment: I create a brand new project and don’t see the using of **UseSpa** in .net6, but I get it in .net3.1. Can you share the sample code and don’t contain sensitive information, so that we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: @Ronaldoz Sorry, I don't think I understand what you're saying. I did share the sample code; I believe that what I shared are the relevant pieces of `Program.cs`, enough to reproduce the issue. Are you trying to tell me that when you generated the default SPA template in .net6 it doesn't include `UseSpa`? You are correct, this app has been migrated several times, but my point is that I _do_ want to continue to use `UseSpa` and I would like to know if that is possible.

Comment: Have you checked/tried the migration guides [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/44600) or [docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/intro?view=aspnetcore-7.0)? Or just ignoring the warning until you are ready to migrate?

Comment: Change `{controller=Home}` to `{controller}` as it was in the old version?

Comment: [The bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77325127/timeline) likely attracted a [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) plagiariser.